# Unable to configure CloudFront distribution with S3 origin and Origin Access Control using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to set up CloudFront distribution with S3 bucket as origin, I have added a policy to the bucket and created Origin Access Control and assigned it to the bucket but when I try to deploy it I get an error `"Invalid request provided: Illegal configuration: The origin type and OAC origin type differ."` Here's my code:

```js
// S3 bucket
export class S3Bucket extends Bucket {
  constructor(scope: Construct) {
    super(scope, S3_BUCKET_NAME, {
      websiteIndexDocument: 'index.html',
      blockPublicAccess: BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL
    });
  }
};

// CloudFront Distribution
export class CloudFrontDistribution extends cloudfront.Distribution {
  constructor(scope: Construct, bucket: Bucket) {
    super(scope, CLOUD_FRONT_DISTRIBUTION_NAME, {
      defaultBehavior: {
        origin: new S3Origin(bucket),
        viewerProtocolPolicy: cloudfront.ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
        compress: true
      }
    });

    const oac = new cloudfront.CfnOriginAccessControl(this, 'MyOriginAccessControl', {
      originAccessControlConfig: {
        name: 'MyOriginAccessControl',
        originAccessControlOriginType: 's3',
        signingBehavior: 'always',
        signingProtocol: 'sigv4'
      }
    });

    const allowOriginAccessIdentityPolicy = new PolicyStatement({
      actions: ['s3:GetObject'],
      principals: [new ServicePrincipal(this.distributionId)],
      effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      resources: [oac.attrId]
    });

    const allowCloudFrontReadOnlyPolicy = new PolicyStatement({
      actions: ['s3:GetObject'],
      principals: [new ServicePrincipal('cloudfront.amazonaws.com')],
      effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      conditions: {
        'StringEquals': {
          "AWS:SourceArn": this.distributionId
        }
      }
    });

    bucket.addToResourcePolicy(allowCloudFrontReadOnlyPolicy)
    bucket.addToResourcePolicy(allowOriginAccessIdentityPolicy)

    const cfnDistribution = this.node.defaultChild as cloudfront.CfnDistribution
    cfnDistribution.addPropertyOverride(
      'DistributionConfig.Origins.0.OriginAccessControlId',
      oac.getAtt('Id')
    )
  };
};
```

In the console I can see that wrong Origin name is set. This is the bucket website endpoint which doesn't allow adding Origin Access Control.
When I change it to the S3 REST API address then OAC appears.
How do I change this in CDK?

Answer (score 2):

I've figured this out. I read CDK source code and it looks like when you create your bucket with

```js
websiteIndexDocument: 'index.html'
```

CDK enables website hosting for the bucket automatically under the hood. It also uses bucket's website endpoint as origin domain (which was my problem). If website hosting is not enabled it creates Origin Access Identity, creates a policy for the bucket to allow access to the bucket only from OAI and it uses bucket's regional domain name as origin's domain. The solution was to remove

```js
websiteIndexDocument: 'index.html'
```

and block public access to the bucket

```js
blockPublicAccess: BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL
```